# converting the image that is converted to base64 string in php and returned as a part of json to image and displaying it in html

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a php code that retrieves image from database and stores it in json by encoding it using base64.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Id,Image FROM $table_first");

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $array=$row;
        $array['Image']=base64_encode($row['Image']);

       $output[]=$array;
    }
echo json_encode($output);
```

now i have a html file where i have to decode this image and display it in a div element. I have no clue as to how to decode the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
     url:"loc.php",
     dataType:'json',
     type:'POST',
      success:function(output) {
               }
 });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> Test page  </p>
<div class="Ch" id="Ch"></div>
```

Here i need to display the ouptut[0].Image(which is in base64 format) inside the div with the id "ch"

Answer (score 0):

Storing images directly in DATABASE is not a good idea. One way which i recommend is to store the image directly in a specific location in your server and then insert the path to the image in the database.You can avoid much hassle by using this method. :) By the way why are you encoding the image to base_64? How are you storing the image in your Database?

Untested(Assuming the path is stored in the database table )

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Id,Image FROM $table_first");

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $image=$row['Image'];
        $id=$row['Id'];
        $output=array("id"=>$id,"image"=>$image);
    }
echo json_encode($output);
```

Then in your ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
     url:"loc.php",
     dataType:'json',
     type:'POST',
      success:function(output) { 
       var imagehtml='<img src="'+output.image+'" alt=""/>';
           $("#Ch").html(imagehtml); //id of the div where you want the image
               }
 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (assuming a png )
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,input_your_base64_from_database_here" />`
Please check [Data_URI_scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and how to display images for more details.